# Which Java library contains the javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet class?

Tags: java, web

I'm working on a NetBeans project and can't seem to get my website to run properly because my internal Apache Tomcat server keeps returning an error that it cannot load the FacesServlet class. Which available library contains this? Currently I have the Java EE Web 7 API and Java DB libraries loaded on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use service like [findjar](http://findjar.com) to find jars that contain some class:

http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html

Comment: That's actually how I found it :P

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just now found out it was under the JSF 2.2 library! Sometimes it just pays to ask to think more about it! :)